# Объединение MixItUp и Owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, плагин, owl-carousel

Я пытаюсь заставить owl-carousel и MixItUp работать вместе

Пока это работает, но owl добавляет дополнительный `div class = "owl-carousel"`, и я хотел бы добавить дополнительный класс, чтобы иметь возможность отфильтровать его.

Есть идеи, как заставить это работать? Должно ли это быть CSS или JS?

Спасибо за вашу помощь!

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/SilverDreams/pen/xoKVmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я собрал массив всех стилей контейнеров и перенес их в родительский элемент создаваемый owl-carousel после того как страница загружалась и выполнялся скрипт owl и mixitup.

```
var arr = $(".mix");
    for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        $(arr[index]).parent().addClass("mix");
        console.log($(arr[index]).attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
        $(arr[index]).parent().addClass($(arr[index]).attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
```